# Traccar API, user information updating failed

Tags: android, api, request, retrofit2, put

I'm trying to update the traccar user password in android,in the documentation I saw that with PUT it's necessary to send the user id, and the information to update, I've already tried this:

```
@PUT("users")
Call<Users> updateUserInformation(@Header("authorization") String credentials,
                                  @Query("id") int id,
                                  @Body Users users);
```

I've tried with the Credential of the signed user and the Credential of the super_user and the error showed is:

> "Method not allowed"
>   okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@7750b1

I've also tried to send the id as a Field

```
@Field("id") int id
```

But still not working.

I wonder if any of you know how to update the user information in traccar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traccar uses standard REST API convention. You need user id in the URL:

```
@PUT("users/{id}")
Call<User> updateUserInformation(@Path("id") long userId, ...);
```